# Camera in landscape mode only

Tags: android, camera, landscape, android-camera-intent

I am starting camera in my application as ,

```
Intent cameraIntent = new  Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

I want camera preview only in landscape mode not in portrait. Please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible you have to make custom camera application for this and  fix your activity to landscape mode.

Comment: ok. But by default it opens the camera in landscape mode but the orientation is also allowed in that where as I do not want this. So there is no solution?

Comment: The reason this rotation is happening is that the Camera assumes the orientation to be horizontal or landscape. The easiest way to correct the rotation is to make our activity appear in landscape mode.

Comment: so you have decided you will go for custom camera ?

Comment: No not yet but would like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't achieve this if you are using the built-in camera app because the manifest of camera app defines `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` which means that camera app will always show the camera in landscape mode.

You can directly use camera class if you really want to achieve your goal but it will be a lot of extra work

Comment: ok. But by default it opens the camera in landscape mode but the orientation is also allowed in that where as I do not want this. So there is no solution?

Comment: No there isn't as far as I know only way is to make your own

Comment: Yeah then you will be able to achieve your goal but that will involve a lot of code as compared to just two line of intent which you are currently doing